# Unable to query mongodb with find in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a MongoDB database that I am querying using NodeJS, I have a collection "service" with 2 fields containing a dbref to another 2 collections ("appareil" & "bus"), so typically a position doc is similar to this:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
        "idService" : ...,
        "codeRoute" : ...,
        "codeCh" : "...",
        "codeConv" : "...",
        "codeLigne" : "...",
        "date" : ISODate("..."),
        "appareil" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
                "_class" : "com.transtu.documents.Appareil",
                "reference" : "...",
                "societe" : DBRef("societe", ObjectId("..."))
        },
        "bus" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
                "_class" : "com.transtu.documents.Bus",
                "code" : "...",
                "immatriculation" : "...",
                "reference" : "...",
                "localisation" : {
                        "x" : ...,
                        "y" : ...
                },
                "societe" : DBRef("societe", ObjectId("..."))
        }
}
```

I tried the following code in NodeJs using the "mongodb" npm module :

```
findService = {};
findService.date = 'ISODate(' + new Date(service.date).toISOString() + ')';
findService.appareil = {_id: 'new ObjectID(' + service.appareil._id + ')'};
findService.bus = {_id: 'new ObjectID(' + service.bus._id + ')'};
findService.codeCh = service.codeCh;
findService.codeConv = service.codeConv;
serviceCollection.find(findService).toArray(function (err, docs) {
                                        if (err) {
                                            console.error('error:...............  ' + JSON.stringify(err));
                                        } else {

                                            //console.log('docs:............ ' + JSON.stringify(docs));
                                            if (docs.length == 0) {
                                            console.log('not found');    serviceCollection.insertOne(service, function (res, err) {
                                                    if (err) {
                                                        //console.error('err: ............: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
                                                    } else {
                                                        //console.log('res: **************: ' + JSON.stringify(res));
                                                    }
                                                });
                                            } else {
                                                console.log('found');
                                                console.log('docs: ****************************** ' + JSON.stringify(docs));
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
```

This code is not working and I always get "not found" answer, but using the mongo client CMD I found a code that worked for me:

```
db.service.find({"date": ISODate("..."), "codeCh": "...", "codeConv": "...", "appareil._id":  ObjectId("..."), "bus._id" :  ObjectId("...")}).pretty()
```

The goal from this find query is to ensure the uniqueness of a combination of 5 fields in the service collection, I tried adding a compound index like this:

```
db.service.ensureIndex( {date:1, appareil:1, bus:1, codeCh:1, codeConv:1}, { unique: true, dropDups: true } )
```

but it didn't work too...

How can I process a find query with only these 5 fields or how to make the combination of these fields unique in the collection settings?

Answer (score 0):

If you see your code. you have `console.log('not found');` in your `else` condition. So, whenever there is no error, you are getting `not found` printed in the `console`. I think your code is working fine.

```
serviceCollection.find(findService)
    .toArray(function (err, docs) {
        if (err) {
           console.error('error:...............  ' + JSON.stringify(err));
        } else {
           console.log('not found');//this will print "not found" if there is no error.
           //rest of the code
        }
    });
```

you should do `console.log('not found');` while checking the length of `docs`.

```
serviceCollection.find(findService)
    .toArray(function (err, docs) {
        if (err) {
           console.error('error:...............  ' + JSON.stringify(err));
        } else {
           if (docs.length == 0) {
              console.log('not found'); //this should be here
              serviceCollection.insertOne(service, function (res, err) {
                 if (err) {
                     //console.error('err: ............: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
                 } else {
                     //console.log('res: **************: ' + JSON.stringify(res));
                 }
              });
           } else {
                console.log('found');
                console.log('docs: ****************************** ' + JSON.stringify(docs));
           }
        }
    });
```

Comment: It's not about the console message, I'm getting duplicated docs in my service collection, I edited my code anyway